# How to run an Android app on both 7-inch table and 10-inch tablet

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am creating an app for both a 10-inch and a 7-inch tablet.

My problem is, on the 10 inch tablet it's not working well. On the 7-inch one it is. I copied small images in the hdpi folder and big images in the xhdpi folder. I tried using below way but I am getting a problem on 10-inch tablets. Here images looking small like that. I thought the 10 inch tablet was also taking hdpi folder images. The app is in landscape mode.

How to make this app for both tablets?

XML files:

```
res/layout-large/main.xml  -----7 inch
res/layout-xlarge/main.xml  -----10 inch
```

Images:

```
res/drawable/hdpi---7 inch images
res/drawable/xhdpi---10 inch images
```

Table dimensions 7 inch:

```
1024 to 600
density 240
ramsize 512
version 3.0
```

Table dimentions 10 inch:

```
1280 to 800
density 160
ramsize 512
version 3.0
```

Answer (score 5):

You've got to use the new qualifiers at the bottom of http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

For example

```
res/layout/main_activity.xml           # For handsets (smaller than 600dp available width)
res/layout-sw600dp/main_activity.xml   # For 7” tablets (600dp wide and bigger) 
res/layout-sw720dp/main_activity.xml   # For 10” tablets (720dp wide and bigger)
```

Comment: thaku for respnse.but how to select sw660dp can u give idea

Comment: You can use layout-sw660dp  It's apparently that simple

Comment: sory i dont know how to crate layout-sw600dp can u help me

Comment: File>Create>Direzctory inside the res folder

Comment: i copeid main.xml inside layout-sw600dp but i ma geeting force close

Comment: inside hdpi image1 size is 70-70 and inside xhdpi image1 size is 120-120.but dont knw about density those image.so i need to give different density to both hdpi and xhdpi images?or not?

Answer (score 0):

HDPI is for density ~= 240
XHDPI is for density ~= 300

Your 10 inch tablet is density 160, which is MDPI.

Also LARGE & XLARGE depends on the screen size (resolution), but  your drawable folders depend on the screen density, which is not the same thing.

Here are all the infos you need : http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: i created emulater 320 density also but my app int this emulater not running

Comment: i follwed method is correct or not whats the prblm can u let me

Comment: I think you should put your layouts in "layout-hdpi" for your 7inch tablet and in "layout-mdpi" for your 10inch one. Because screen density is more "important" than screen size. ALSO put your 10inch drawable in drawable-MDPI because your 10" tablet is MDPI not XHDPI.